# Action of comparatives on connected clauses

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, comparatives

Consider the sentence

> Though somewhat less (i) _____than previous chapters and suffering from a minor rash of academic jargon, the final chapter of the book is nonetheless (ii) ______laypeople.

How would I know on which parts is the word "less" acting on?

For example, I can parse the first part of the sentence as asserting "The previous chapter is less _____ (arcane) and suffering less from jargon." or I can parse it as "The previous chapter is less _____ (coherent) and suffering from jargon." The second interpretation is the one that's considered correct.

So if I take it as a rule that given a sentence of the from "A is less B and C", it implies "A is less B" and "A is C", wouldn't such a rule contradict with the canonical interpretation of the sentence "Pizza is less healthy and tasty." which implies "Pizza is less tasty."?

More precisely, why am I not allowed to interpret "less arcane and suffering" as "less arcane and less suffering" when I can interpret "less healthy and tasty" as "less healthy and less tasty"?

Comment: 'less [arcane than previous chapters and suffering from ...]' is infelicitous. You'd need 'less arcane than previous chapters, and suffering less from academic jargon]'. You can't have (however cunningly concealed) 'less suffering from'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, but that is my question. Why am I not allowed to interpret "less arcane and suffering" as "less arcane and less suffering" when I can interpret "less healthy and tasty" as "less healthy and less tasty"?

Comment: Because the implied 'I am less suffering from the disease than John is' is unacceptable. 'X is less A and B' in general can mean 'X is B, and less A' but the default sense is 'X is less A and less B'. But 'less B' has to be acceptable _and in that order_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth
So the only reason "less suffering" isn't permitted is because "less suffering" ≠ "suffering less"? If that's the case, thank you very much for your response. I suppose this distribution of "less" doesn't work when one side contains a verb.

Comment: You can say *less annoying* (and similar constructions), but [*annoying*](https://www.lexico.com/definition/annoying) is an adjective in this phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why am I not allowed to interpret "less arcane and suffering" as "less arcane and less suffering" when I can interpret "less healthy and tasty" as "less healthy and less tasty"?

This seems to be the crux of the actual question.The answer is simple: you can.

However, *suffering* is a noun, not an adjective, and that makes the phrase so unidiomatic as to be unacceptable without a slight change.

---

The following are wrong:

> ✘ Less **healthy** and **taste**.
> ✘ Less **health** and **tasty**.

The following are fine:

> ✔ Less **health** and **taste**.
> ✔ Less **healthy** and **tasty**.

It's not a matter of grammar, strictly speaking, but of parallelism (style) and how, in this case, mixing a noun with an adjective makes the construction so awkward as to be considered wrong.

The problem is not with the expansion of *less*—which does work with each word individually—but with the category of each word used in the pair.

---

*Arcana* is the noun form of the adjective *arcane*:.

This is wrong:

> ✘ Less **arcane** and ***suffering***.
> ✘ Less ***arcana*** and **sufferable**.

This is fine:

> ✔  Less **arcane** and ***sufferable***.

But *aracana*, being countable, is normally paired with *fewer*, not *less*, so the phrase can't be reduced when *less* is used:

> ？ Less ***arcana*** and **suffering**.
> ✔ *Fewer* ***arcana*** and less **suffering**.

Answer (score 0):

The *final* chapter is less (  ) than previous chapters, and [it] suffers from [a small amount] of academic jargon, but [it] is nonetheless (   ) [to?] laypeople.

Comment: Then shouldn't "Pizza is less healthy and tasty" also read as "Pizza is less healthy and [it is] tasty." instead of "Pizza is less healthy and less tasty."?

Comment: The two are not exactly comparable.  The passage you quote appears to be making two criticisms of the final chapter, while you are saying one negative and one positive thing about pizza. 'Pizza is less healthy, _but_ tasty' would work.

Comment: But if you interpret it as "less arcane and less suffering from jargon (as compared to other chapters)", then it is not a criticism. My question is if there are any syntactical rules which prevent the "less" from getting distributed across the connectives?

Comment: I wouldn't interpret it that way. _Though_ implies that both things that follow are negative. As Edwin says, to get the other meaning you would have to say _...and suffering less from..._

Comment: Isn't "though" mainly a contrast, rather than necessarily negative? For example, in the sentence "Though he is very fast, he still lost the race", 'though' doesn't imply a negative. If such is permitted, we can have the above sentence as 
"Though less arcane and less suffering from jargon, it was nonetheless inaccessible to laypeople."

Comment: I meant that _in that particular sentence_ 'though' implies that both are negative, _in contrast to_ what follows 'nonetheless', which I would expect to be positive (accessible to laypeople?). Why are there blanks in the sentence,  and do you know what words _should_ be there?